# what does "Most of Brisbane's here" mean?

Tags: semantics

Transcript at this TEDxSydney talk [video](https://www.ted.com/talks/tom_thum_the_orchestra_in_my_mouth/transcript?language=en), at 4:10

> You know, I'm from Brisbane, which is a great city to live
> in.(Applause and shouts from the audience) Yeah! All right! **Most of
> Brisbane's here.** That's good. (Laughter)

I assume the transcript above provided by the official website is accurate.

I think Brisbane in the transcript refers to the city, not the people in that city, right? As to **Most of Brisbane's here**, I have two guesses:

1, Most of those who are applauding are from Brisbane.

2, Most people from Brisbane have come here.

Comment: This might be called [metonymy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metonymy) or [synecdoche](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synecdoche): the speaker does not literally mean "most of the city of Brisbane", but "most of the people who live in the city of Brisbane".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 2, most of the people from Brisbane are in the audience.

In this context it does refer to the people from the city, and is a colloquial way of saying "Most of the population of Brisbane's here".

I can't justify it linguistically, but the general assumption would be that anyone who responded positively to his mention of Brisbane would be from there (as when a singer at a concert asks "is anyone from [place] in tonight?" and everyone from there cheers!) so the statement that "most of those applauding are from Brisbane" is unlikely ever to be needed!